# Flixel - How do I make FlxGroups appear on just one FlxCamera?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, flixel

I have a Flixel project with multiple `FlxCamera`'s. One of them is the main play area, and another is the radar display within the HUD to the right of the main area. I want to add a layer (`FlxGroup`) to just the radar camera, and I also want to exclude my other layers from the radar camera so they don't randomly show up in the radar's area.

My question is, how do I tell the cameras to only show objects in certain `FlxGroup`'s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured this out on my own. Each object needs to be given a reference to an `Array` containing references to the `FlxCamera` objects you want it shown on, and this needs to happen (usually) when the object is first made. The first time a `FlxObject` calls `update()`, if its `cameras` is null, it assigns `FlxG.cameras` as a default, which means all of the active cameras will display the object.

I did this by making a few static `Array`'s in my Main class, one for each camera group, and then in the constructor for my various classes, I would set their `cameras` variable to point to the corresponding `Array`.

The biggest frustration: Currently `FlxGroup` does not pass its `cameras` on to its members. Hopefully this will be added into future versions of Flixel so that `FlxGroup`'s can be assigned a camera group and have all their children also automatically assigned the same camera group.

Comment: +1. In your frustration you might consider visiting their [Contribute](http://flixel.org/contribute.html) page and suggesting less frustrating implementations that they could add.

Comment: Thanks for that link, I just submitted my suggestion.